# Transistor as a switch not working as expected

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, current-measurement, npn

[image: Circuit Diagram]

In the above circuit, the transistor is an NPN 2N2222 model. The RC resistor is actually a very small water pump (which I believe is a DC motor) that uses about 60mA across a 5V potential difference, hence the 85 Ohm resistor to represent it.

My issue is that when I set this up in real life with a Raspberry Pi supplying the 5V and 3.3V from its pins, the motor does not turn on.

Sometimes if I power the base then disconnect and reconnect the power, it briefly turns on.

Wierdly, when I measure the current going through the pump (with  the base pin high), it increases to about 240mA then goes to 0. If I disconnect and reconnect the power this happens again.

I'm quite new to transistors so would be grateful for any help possible. If changes need to be made to my circuit I would be grateful to end up with as simple circuit as possible with as few transistors as possible as well.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: We generally draw schematics with ground at the bottom and supplies at the top.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in principle with your circuit, though I would use a logic-level FET and not a bipolar.  You will also need a flyback diode across the motor coil, could be you are damaging your transistor with the inductive kick on turn-off.  Also make sure you aren't reversing the emitter and collector.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very experienced with drawing schematics. I did originally mix up the base and emitter but have definitely sorted that out now. I considered putting a diode in but surely if it works without a diode without the transistor it should work the same way with the transistor too?

Comment: Did you connect the grounds? https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/the-importance-of-sharing-grounds/

Comment: @Majenko Yes, I did

Comment: 250mA, what's the voltage on the motor during this?

Comment: With a 1000Ω resistor on the base, and assuming a beta of 100, 250mA is about the limit of the current that can flow. What is the stall current for your pump?

Comment: @Jasen Roughly 5V, but it drops to 0 like the current.

Comment: @Majenko Sorry, the pump doesn't really have any data that comes with it nor a part number.

Comment: You can work out the stall current by measuring the DC resistance using a DMM. Use that with Ohm's law to find the current at your supply voltage of 5V (I=V/R) - that is the minimum current you will need to allow to pass through the transistor.

Comment: @Majenko Using your method, the resistance was 1.18 Mega Ohms giving me a stall current of 42.4 micro Amps.

Comment: @Majenko However, I may have misunderstood your method. At 5V, the pump draws 60mA (without the transistor), is this the stall current?

Comment: The stall current is the current required to start the motor spinning. This is considerably higher than the normal run current. The peak stall current is the point at which the motor is just about to move, which is governed by the DC resistance of the coil in the motor.

Comment: It could be that the motor in your pump is a brushless one, which has a small controller embedded in it to activate a number of coils in sequence. You won't be able to measure the stall current on that kind of motor.

Comment: @Majenko Ok, thanks for your help. I'm going to get a diode and see whether that works, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can a) reduce the value of your base resistor to allow more current through. b) replace the BJT with a logic level FET. Either way you want to add the diode connected backwards across the motor to absorb any back-EMF generated by the coils.

Comment: Great, I'll try your suggestions. Many thanks again for helping me!

Comment: To make sure I understand, when you put 5V across the pump with the pump actually pumping the fluid you get 60mA.  This would be the running current and indicates this is a very small motor.  Stall current occurs if you put 5V across the motor and hold the shaft so it can't turn.  This should be much higher than the running current. Does the motor or transistor get hot when it should be on but is not pumping?

Comment: @owg60 I cannot access the motor itself so cannot hold the shaft but you are correct about the running current. I am pumping water but the pump runs fine without a liquid. Nothing appears to be getting particularly hot.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your setup showing the electronics?  You are right, this is pretty straight forward and should work. Typically in circuits like this you set an IC/IB ratio instead of looking at beta.  10 would be good so you can try reducing your base resistor to 420 Ohms.

Answer (score 1):

I think your switch is not strong enough for the starting current required by the motor. try reducing the base resistor to 330, or boost the base current with an emitter follower.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33OMz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

THe mosfet suggested by others is also an option.